# rsyslog (exit status 0; not expected)

Tags: supervisord

Before:

```
root@haproxy:/# ps aux | grep rsyslog
root       420  0.0  0.1   8860   648 ?        S+   12:38   0:00 grep --color=auto rsyslog
```

Start Supervisord and error:

```
root@haproxy:/# /usr/bin/supervisord
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/supervisor/options.py:295: UserWarning: Supervisord is running as root and it is searching for its configuration file in default locations (including its current working directory); you probably want to specify a "-c" argument specifying an absolute path to a configuration file for improved security.
  'Supervisord is running as root and it is searching '
2015-11-25 12:06:59,742 CRIT Supervisor running as root (no user in config file)
2015-11-25 12:06:59,743 WARN Included extra file "/etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf" during parsing
2015-11-25 12:06:59,769 INFO RPC interface 'supervisor' initialized
2015-11-25 12:06:59,770 CRIT Server 'unix_http_server' running without any HTTP authentication checking
2015-11-25 12:06:59,770 INFO supervisord started with pid 211
2015-11-25 12:07:00,774 INFO spawned: 'rsyslog' with pid 214
2015-11-25 12:07:00,845 INFO exited: rsyslog (exit status 0; not expected)
2015-11-25 12:07:01,849 INFO spawned: 'rsyslog' with pid 232
2015-11-25 12:07:01,874 INFO exited: rsyslog (exit status 0; not expected)
2015-11-25 12:07:03,879 INFO spawned: 'rsyslog' with pid 243
2015-11-25 12:07:03,902 INFO exited: rsyslog (exit status 0; not expected)
2015-11-25 12:07:06,907 INFO spawned: 'rsyslog' with pid 254
2015-11-25 12:07:06,926 INFO exited: rsyslog (exit status 0; not expected)
2015-11-25 12:07:07,928 INFO gave up: rsyslog entered FATAL state, too many start retries too quickly
```

After:

```
root@haproxy:/# ps aux | grep rsyslog
syslog     435  0.1  0.2 116572  1208 ?        Ssl  12:39   0:00 /usr/sbin/rsyslogd
root       474  0.0  0.1   8860   648 ?        S+   12:39   0:00 grep --color=auto rsyslog
```

File `/etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf`:

```
[supervisord]
nodaemon=true

[program:rsyslog]
command=service rsyslog start
startsecs=5
```

I can start up `rsyslog` manually without any issue with:

```
service rsyslog start
```

So as you can see, before I go ahead and start supervisord rsyslog is not running. After I run the supervisord it does indeed start rsyslog however spawns and exits. Anyone know the reason behind this?

Answer (score 1):

Found this little diamond which works:

```
[program:rsyslog]
command=rsyslogd -n -c5
autostart=true
autorestart=true
redirect_stderr=true
```